# Assigning Pointers to the first and last indexes of an String Object

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am trying to write a function that takes a user submitted string and creates two pointers; one pointing to the first index of the string and one pointing to the last index of the string.  I am getting an error when I try and set the pointers equal to the specific indexes `firstPointer = userString[0];
    secondPointer = userString[userString.length() - 1];`.  The error i'm receiving is appearing on the `=` operator and says "A value of type char can not be assigned to an entity of type char".

I've read several other posts on stackoverflow and I don't think they're addressing the same issue or it's plausible i'm not understanding what they're recommending.  I'm fairly new to C++ and am new to pointers.  You can ignore the for loop I was just setting that up when I realized my assignment of the pointers was throwing an error.  Please find the function code below:

**Function**

```
void ReverseString(string &userString)
{

    char *firstPointer;
    char *secondPointer;

    firstPointer = new char;
    secondPointer = new char;

    firstPointer = userString[0];
    secondPointer = userString[userString.length() - 1];

    //Iterate over entire string
    for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < userString.length()/2; loopCounter++)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: `firstPointer = new char;` for what purpose do you have these lines?

Comment: Initialization should be `secondPointer = &userString[userString.length() - 1];`

Comment: See [std::basic_string::operator\[\]](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at).

Comment: Oh!  That fixed it, but why?  I'm confused I thought you had to initialize the pointers first and then set them elsewhere by using new "type"?

Comment: Also see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Comment: @StormsEdge You don't need to allocate memory for a pointer if you're pointing it at an existing point in memory

Comment: Also for those that down voted my question I feel the need to reiterate straight from the FAQ: No question is too trivial or too "newbie". Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know.  Yes, my question contains a syntax error, but I don't believe that constitutes it as a bad question.  If my question is poor please let me know why so that I might fix it rather than just down voting it.  This, in essence, prevents stack overflow from being exclusive and makes it inclusive IMO.

Comment: The tooltip for the downvote button says: *"This question does not show any research effort"*. The question clearly fits that condition.

Comment: @IInspectable I disagree entirely.  Please find me a question that relates directly to this; I also quoted that it's possible i'm not understanding something from other questions, which if i'm not mistaken, would explain for the error.  Referencing a book and a link to Cpp documentation is hardly a reference to anything on the site.

Comment: @IInspectable not to mention the documentation you tagged me in is in German, which frankly is useless to me as I do not speak German.

Comment: [Click here for the English version of this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at).

Comment: @StormsEdge: "Research" doesn't just mean "Stack Overflow" - there are a number of other types of resource out there, and asking questions on SO is a *really* bad way to learn the language.  A good book (preferably aimed at the sort of experience you already have), is much more likely to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error I'm receiving is appearing on the `=` operator and says 
>   "A value of type char can not be assigned to an entity of type char".

I don't believe you.  I am prepared to bet a significant sum that it actually says:
"A value of type char can not be assigned to an entity of type char *****"

That trailling * is vitally important.  `firstPointer` is not a `char`, it is a "pointer to `char`", or as we tend to say here "a `char*`".

`userString[0]` on the other hand, *is* a `char` (or more precisely, a reference to a `char`).  It is a reference to the character in the string at index 0.  If you want a pointer to that `char`, you need to take its address.  So `&userString[0]`.  So your code could be:

```
    firstPointer = &userString[0];
    secondPointer = &userString[userString.length() - 1];
```

Alternatively, getting the first and the last element is so common that there are specific functions for that, so you can write:

```
    firstPointer = &userString.front();
    secondPointer = &userString.back();
```

Finally, *all* of this depends on there actually *being* a first and last character - so you should really start with:

```
    if (userString.empty()) return;
```

to make sure there is.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
void ReverseString(string &userString)
{

    char *firstPointer;
    char *secondPointer;

    firstPointer = &userString[0];
    secondPointer = &userString[userString.length() - 1];

    .....

}
```

Your problem is your userString isn't a pointer. A pointer is like the address of the actual object. So doing this: `firstPointer = userString[0];` is like giving someone your house when they asked for your address. But you can get the "address" by using the `&` operator, like so `firstPointer = &userString[0];`.

You also don't need to use `new` in this situation. You would write something like `firstPointer = new char;` if you wanted your pointer to point to something that until that point didn't exist, effectively creating a new `char` and pointing to it. But, since the `userString` already exists, there is no need to create a new one.

Comment: Code-only answers are hardly ever useful. Unless you explain, what the issue is, and how your proposed solution addresses that, it isn't very helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable - Good advice, I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks.